# withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC) of DateTimeFormatter changing the value of date

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format, java-6

I have a below code

```
    final DateTimeFormatter COMBINED_FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withZone(
                DateTimeZone.UTC);
         System.out.println(COMBINED_FORMAT.parseDateTime("2012-04-01T00:00:00.000").toDate());
```

Result is **Sun Apr 01 05:30:00 IST 2012**
I expect this to return **Sun Apr 01 00:00:00 IST 2012**

How can I get this?

Comment: If you are expecting the timezone to be IST why are you using UTC? What happens if you use the IST timezone? If you are in the IST timezone why are you setting it at all?

Comment: You call `toDate()` on the parsed `DateTime` which returns a `java.util.Date`; when you print this, it's always printed in your local timezone. Note that a `java.util.Date` does not remember any timezone information.

Comment: "India Standard Time (IST) is 5:30 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time." from http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist . ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey , This is a standalone application ,I have a project where it runs on different timezone . So the resultant I want as **Sun Apr 01 00:00:00 IST 2012**

Comment: @Ganesh in that case I would parse it as a date time in the IST timezone.

Comment: @jesper I don't want to append +5.30 to input I pass

Comment: @PeterLawrey by default value ex: +5:30 (IST) is getting added if I run on Indian time zone , If I same code by changing to US time 

result is **Sat Mar 31 19:00:00 CDT 2012**(-06:00 is substacted)

Comment: @krzyk any reasons why you removed java-6 and added java-8?

Comment: @assylias I assumed it is for DateTimeFormatter from java 8, there was no tag for joda time at that time

Comment: There is a backport for JSR-310 on Java 6, but Java 8 is what I assumed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There is no ISODateTimeFormat in jsr310 (or any toDate methods) but there is in jodatime so I suspect the question is about Joda.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not use `java.util.Date.toString()` (implicitly used in your example) to evaluate the result. Reason is its confusing behaviour to always output in your system timezone and not the real state of your result.

Second: If you set the zone to UTC then you instruct your parser to interprete the zone-less string "2012-04-01T00:00:00.000" as UTC and not as IST. Just look at the state of your result:

```
DateTimeFormatter COMBINED_FORMAT =
  ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(COMBINED_FORMAT.parseDateTime("2012-04-01T00:00:00.000"));
// 2012-04-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

However, if you want the result to be "Sun Apr 01 00:00:00 IST 2012" (output of date.toString()) or equivalent: "2012-04-01T00:00:00+05:30" then you have to instruct the parser to interprete the input as IST and not UTC.

**Solution:**

```
DateTimeFormatter COMBINED_FORMAT =
    ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(COMBINED_FORMAT.parseDateTime("2012-04-01T00:00:00.000"));
// 2012-04-01T00:00:00.000+05:30
```